# 'NoneType' object is not iterable BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the number of the A Tag where a value is located.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.sortlist.fr/pub'
response= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
counter = 1
links = soup.find("a",{"class": "s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate md-sortlist-theme"})
for link in links:  
  soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')
  print (counter)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

----- Update -------

What I actually want to do ( I realized that I am not very clear) is to return the number in which the value was found (I want to determine the position of the Dupont Lewis within the listings) hence counting the A tags. So it should look inside the tags if I find the value, I need to return the number of the A otherwise keep going through them until I do find it. I am trying this now, but something is still a miss:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.sortlist.fr/pub"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")
links = soup.find(
    "a", {"class": "s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate"}
)
def increment():
    counter=0
    for link in links:
      if soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]'):
        print(counter)
      else increment()
        print(counter)
```

Comment: It's telling you `soup.find()` didn't find anything. Consider examining `response.content` to make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: There is no `a` element with class `s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate md-sortlist-theme` but there is with `s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate` (Inspecting source code on chrome), `find` does not return anything if it fails, but find_all returns an empty list

Comment: See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ : If find_all() can’t find anything, it returns an empty list. If find() can’t find anything, it returns None

Answer (score 2):

Your class is not bringing and results from soup.find. By shortening the class I was able to get the result you were looking for:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.sortlist.fr/pub'
response= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
counter = 1
links = soup.find("a",{"class": "md-headline"})
for link in links:  
    result = soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')
    if result:
        counter += 1 # increment counter instead of just printing 1
        print(result)
```

Result:
`<a class="s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate" ng-click='setExpertiseAndLocation({"expertise":{"id":84,"name":"Publicité","title":"Agences de Publicité","slug":"pub","imageUrl":"/images/expertises/84.jpg"}})' sl-link="xx-L2FnZW5jeS9kdXBvbnQtbGV3aXM=" target="_blank" title="Dupont Lewis">Dupont Lewis</a>`

Answer (score 1):

If we print the `soup` object, we see that the is actually under the class `s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

counter = 1

URL = "https://www.sortlist.fr/pub"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find(
    "a", {"class": "s-block s-bold md-headline md-padding s-pb0 md-truncate"}
)

for link in links:
    if soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]'):
        counter += 1

print(counter) # Output: 2
```